# can't connect a client machine to a (byo) sql machine within the same subnet

Tags: sql-server, azure

i did read multiple other posts but was not able to solve my problem.High Level: my Sql Client cannot connect to my Sql Server

I created 3 virtual machines with Azure (they all use the same affinity group):

I created two subnets:

192.168.0.0/29 (ADDC)

172.16.0.0/22 (CLIENTS)

1) Win2008R2 as DomainServer (subnet ADDC)

2) Win2008R2 as SQLServer (subnet CLIENTS)

3) Win2008R2 as Application Server / SQL Client (subnet CLIENTS)

Problem:

my application in machine 3) does not "see" the sql server. Next I tried to ping the SQLSERVER. The dns Name gets resolved but now ping packet is received.

(I deactivated Firewall for Domain on both machines).

Further I created and Endpoint on machine 2) for SQL TCP 1433

Machine 2) and 3) can ping 1) successfully!

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION (edited):
I just deactivated my firewall for "public networks" and now it works! Since I am logged on both machine as a domain user I am very confused why that is necessary.
As a temporary workaround i will activate Port 143 for puplic networks, but clarification would be great!

appreciate your help!